# Customizing Linq-to-SQL DBML template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, interface, code-templates

I am using Linq-to-sql for generating code for database interaction. I need the generated code to include Interfaces for each concrete class, and believe the only easy way to achieve this is to modify the Linq-to-SQL code generating template.

I have seen a guide by Damien Guard (http://damieng.com/blog/2008/09/14/linq-to-sql-template-for-visual-studio-2008), however I have 2 constraints prohibiting the approach:

1. I am on VS2010; and
2. I am working on a Dev environment in which I cannot install non-approved tools/etc.

Are there any other ways to modify how the Linq-to-sql code is generated the template for VS2010 that do not require installing 3rd party templates/etc?

Alternatively, are there any other easy ways to reverse engineer Interfaces to match existing concrete classes?